# Print counter for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to know if there is any software by which I may know how many pages are printed from specific date to specific date.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but some information can be retrieved from CUPS. For example: http://localhost:631/printers/PDF?which_jobs=completed